# Generating Functions related to Candy problem with that twist (Updated)

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Let a(n) denote the number of ways of distributing  candies to  kids without distributing a multiple of m candies to any kid. Write generating function a() of the sequence {a(n)}.

I approached the question from the generating functions side, but no solution.

P.S I already submitted this empty, but i am too desperate to find the answer. Thanks for your help already

Edit:

i tried using
$ 1/(1-x) - x^3/(1-x)$  and $  1/(1-x) - 1/(1-x^3) + 1$

they both generate the same polynmial

```
                    (sum_(m=0)^∞ x^m) - (sum_(m=1)^∞ x^3m)
```

the problem starts at taking the k-th power of the sum and tried using wolframalpha and my self knowledge to find an infinite sum containing only single variable index.

i am always stuck at that point. i went through my special notes by my instructor's friend ( because he's more of a cryptographer and also he stated at the start that he also wants to improve). More importantly, i just cannot understand combinatorics(i mean counting problems, in that manner)

I would also appreciate any book that is easier to understand cuz I am more of a good listener than a reader. Still like reading.

Thanks for your help already

Comment: I already posted this question but could not follow. I was stuck at home for 3 months and i just went to my hometown for some fresh air. I am not that technologically advanced. My phone is only good at calling. I did not mean to post it and leave it as it is. I am truly sorry. Hopefully I or we can find an answer to this.  I looked at my scratches and still no development.

Comment: What's the connection to distribution-theory?

Comment: Are the candies distinguishable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the other way around. The generating function of the number of candies one particular kid gets is:

$\begin{align*}
c(z)
  &= \sum_{\substack{k \ge 0 \\
                     m \not\mid k}} z^k \\
  &= \sum_{k \ge 0} z^k - \sum_{k \ge 0} z^{m k} \\
  &= \frac{1}{1 - z} - \frac{1}{1 - z^m}
\end{align*}$

If there are (n) kids, the generating function is:

$\begin{align*}
  g(z)
    &= c^n(z) \\
    &= \left(\frac{1}{1 - z} - \frac{1}{1 - z^m}\right)^n \\
    &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n} (-1)^{n - k} \binom{n}{k}
          \frac{1}{(1 - z)^k (1 - z^m)^{n - k}} \\
    &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n} (-1)^{n - k} \binom{n}{k}
         \cdot \left(
                 \sum_{r \ge 0} \binom{k + r - 1}{k - 1} z^r
               \right)
         \cdot \left(
                 \sum_{s \ge 0} \binom{n - k + s - 1}{n - k - 1} z^{m s}
               \right) \\
    &= \sum_{\substack{0 \le k \le n \\
                       r \ge 0 \\
                       s \ge 0}}
          (-1)^{n - k} \binom{n}{k}
               \binom{k + r - 1}{k - 1}
               \binom{n - k + s - 1}{n - k - 1}
             z^{r + m s}       
\end{align*}$

From this mess you want the coefficient of $z^N$ if you have $N$ candies:

$\begin{align*}
   [z^N] g(z)
     &= \sum_{\substack{0 \le k \le n \\
                        r \ge 0 \\
                        s \ge 0 \\
                        r + m s = N}}
           (-1)^{n - k} \binom{n}{k}
               \binom{k + r - 1}{k - 1}
               \binom{n - k + s - 1}{n - k - 1} \\
\end{align*}$

We could work some more on the summation condition $0 \le k \le n \wedge r \ge 0 \wedge s \ge 0 \wedge r + s m = N$ to get rid of $r$, but it is very unlikely that the resulting sum has any closed form solution.

The way forward is as outlined in Petkovsek et al ["A = B"](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html). The relevant algorithms to reduce such sums to closed forms (or prove they don't exist) are too much work for hand computation, fortunately most computer algebra systems have them, possibly as add-ons.